# Combining C++11 and TR1-dependent code in OSX?

Tags: c++11, xcode4.2, googletest, tr1, clang++

I have a C++11 project that uses Google Test, and it builds great in Linux. On a Mac, I am having more difficulty integrating it into my code base. The issue seems to be that while my code uses C++11, the Google code uses TR1. As a result, TR data structures like `enum` and `unordered_set` are included differently.

The Google Test samples build and run perfectly as provided. The samples also build just fine if I use clang++ instead of g++. (My code works only on clang++, so I use that to build.) Finally, Google's code also builds and runs if I use `-std=c++11`.

However, Google test does *not* build using clang++ on my mac if I use `-stdlib=libc++`. It reports that it cannot find tr1/tuple, which, of course, is true. This is a problem, because *my* code does not build if I use `-stdlib=libstdc++` (or no `stdlib` argument).

Of course, I could switch all of my code over to the older standard. This, however, is extremely yuck. Is there a way to make these code bases live happily side-by-side on the Mac?

My code builds happily with Google test using g++ 4.6.3 on an Ubuntu 12.04 computer. The mac is running OSX 10.8.3. It's running g++ 4.2.1 and clang 4.2++.

Thanks for any help,
David

PS: I am somewhat new to C++, so forgive me if this is a foolish question.

Edit: Changed "OS/X" to "OSX." (Yes, I am that old.)

Comment: Which compilers and which versions are you using on MacOSX? I believe that if you built GCC 4.8 on your Mac it will compile your code as well as Linux does! Most Linux have newer GCC than 4.2 today!

Answer (score 1):

You can instruct Google test to use its own implementation of tr1::tuple

In cmake I use the following line to compile with "old" compilers:

```
add_definitions(-DGTEST_HAS_TR1_TUPLE=0)
```

I'm sure you can add it to your build system, it's a simple preprocessor definition.

You can look at [include/gtest/internal/gtest-port.h](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/source/browse/trunk/include/gtest/internal/gtest-port.h) for more options. GTEST_USE_OWN_TR1_TUPLE may be useful. Most of the parameters are correct with default values.